# Cíclo que crea data.frames

Tags: r, bucles, dataframe

saludos a todos los que lean mi pregunta, agradecería de antemano que tuviera solución.

El problema es el siguiente, recibí un archivo de excel que contiene una variable llamada "Persona", esta avriable contiene 452 números diferentes, el objetivo es crear 452 dataframes, donde cada uno de esos dataframes será un subset del dataframe original con un único valor de "Persona".

Es decir, quiero separar el dataframe original en los 452 dataframes que corresponderían a cada "Persona"

Por ahora tengo el código siguiente, traté de darle una solución simple.

```
# Leer el excel
library(readxl)
datos<-read_excel("datos.xlsx")

# Extraer las personas
personas<-c()

for (i in datos$Persona) {
                          personas[i] <- i
                         }
# Quitar los na del vector personas, esto es porqué el ciclo de arriba guarda NA´s en las posiciones 
donde no hay "Persona" registrada.

personas2<-subset(personas, is.na(personas)==FALSE)

# Mirar cuántas personas son en total
length(personas2)

# Crear el ciclo de dataframes
# La idea era crear 452 dataframes distintos, cada uno llamado i (donde 1 irá desde 1 hasta 452), 
# seleccionando uno a uno el "Personas"  
for (i in 1:452) {
                   i <- subset(datos, Persona==personas2[i])
                 }
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda.
Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, no puedes nombrar ninguna variable empezando con un número, si podrías eventualmente algo así: `df1, df2, dfn`, pero no te recomiendo que trabajes de esta forma, es innecesariamente más complejo.

Si realmente necesitas manejar los datos de forma separada, lo que se puede hacer en R y en cualquier otro lenguaje, es usar una colección de datos, en este caso una lista, dónde cada elemento será un `data.frame` distinto:

```
lista_personas = list()
for (i in 1:452) {
    lista_personas[i] <- subset(datos, Persona==personas2[i])
}
```

Luego, para referencias cada `data.frame` por el índice:

```
lista_personas[[1]]
lista_personas[[2]]
..
lista_personas[[452]]
```